# Actionscript broken?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

My Flash is a little strange, I doesn't recognize the UILoader I'm importing, actually when I type `import fl.c` it doesn't suggest the container library, was this deleted in AS3 or is flash just broken?

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.containers.UILoader;



public class Tarjetas extends MovieClip {


    public function Tarjetas() {
        var loader:UILoader = new UILoader();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I’ve never heard of `fl.containers.UILoader`. Maybe try `flash.display.Loader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILoader` is a component (like `FLVPlayback`) which means the component itself needs to be added to your library for the above to work.

This may help:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as3_components_help.pdf